# Как понять,что поле равно NULL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Пусть в таблице есть поле Age типа Int в некоторой таблице,которое может быть NUL.
Пусть есть уже полученный ResultSet rs.
И вот код для взятия значения этого поля из таблицы

```
  while(rs.hasnext())
{
 rs.next.getInt("Age");
}
```

По идее,если поле Age  = null,то rs.next.getInt("Age") вернет 0.
Но как понять,что поле  Age  = null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по
[документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()),
для этого есть метод `wasNull`:

```java
int age = rs.getInt("Age")
if (rs.wasNull()) {
    System.out.println("NULL")
} else {
    System.out.println(age)
}
```